# How to read records from Kafka using Kafka-Stream by interval

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

i want to use in Kafka-Stream consumer to read record from Kafka, there is an option to read the records every given interval? for example every 1 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. However, I think there are multiple approaches (depending on what you actually want to achieve which in unclear from the question).

1. Use Kafka Streams DSL (Kafka 0.10): Using Kafka Streams (a Java stream processing library) you can specify a window aggregation as a tumbling window of any size
2. Exploit timestamps (Kafka 0.10): if you want to use `KafkaConsumer` you can just read messages and check their timestamps to chunk data by intervals
3. System-time based (all Kafka versions): just read messages from Kafka and put messaged in intervals bases in system time. Ie, before you process the next record, you check your local clock to put messages in intervals.

Comment: What I mean is, there is an option to pull the data from Kafka every 1 minute (for example: in 10:01 read all the records from 10:00 to 10:01, in 10:02 read all the records from 10:01 to 10:02, etc.), instead of getting the new records in runtime?
I want to read data for processing every given interval, instead of holding the data in memory until the processing.

Comment: There is no built-in support for this because Kafka is pull based. You need to put this logic into the client using one of the suggested approaches. If I understand you comment correctly, you might want to use approach (3) in combination to get the current end-of-log offsets before starting to poll() and only consumer messages to the obtained offsets (to avoid reading records that are added after you start consuming)

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, I have similar requirement (continuous processing of the records published in last x hour interval). Isn't it possible using Kafka Stream DSL API with hopping window?

Comment: Yes, that would fall into (1) -- depending on your requirements, hopping, tumbling, or sliding windows (added in v2.7.0) might work for you.